# Azure B2C Custom Policy Has Create Button for SignUpSignIn and ProfileEdit Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am currently experiencing a problem with Azure B2C IEF Custom Policy. In my "ProfileEdit" UserJourney The user is presented with the sign-in screen. The problem here is that the continue button is actually labeled "Create" After the user signs in, they are presented with a Edit Profile Page. But again, the continue button is labeled as create.

I have done a lot of research. I could not find anything in stackoverflow and I have reviewed Microsoft Documentation and also ensured that the DataURIs are correct for the ContentDefinition.

The current Data URI is as follows:

urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.1.0

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: curious why it is showing like that... try corss checking with latest starterpacks. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize any element text using [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization).

The first step is to [enable localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#set-up-the-explicit-list-of-supported-languages) for English and any other languages to be supported:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  ...
  <ContentDefinitions />
  <Localization>
    <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en">
      <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
    </SupportedLanguages>
  </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

The second step is to define [the localized strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids) for each supported language for each page definition:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  ...
  <Localization>
    <SupportedLanguages />
    <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate.en">
      <LocalizedStrings>
         <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Update</LocalizedString>
      </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
  </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

The last step is to [declare references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#edit-the-contentdefinition-for-the-page) from the page definition to the localized resources:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  ...
  <ContentDefinitions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate">
      ...
      <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
         <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.selfasserted.profileupdate.en" />
      </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
    </ContentDefinition>
  </ContentDefinitions>
  <Localization />
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your post. After reading your post I reviewed my localization content and discovered that the continue button is actually labeled create and the source of my problem is do to my own doing.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to go with localization. You can still update button/ label values inside Metadata of relevant technical profiles.

For your scenario

> Add new Metadata Item in Base file technical profile
>   **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** like below

```
<Metadata>
 ---
 <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
</Metadata>
```

Comment: Ramakrishna, Thank you. I was not aware that you can label the buttons in the MetaData.